# How to start activity from service in Android10

Tags: android, android-10.0

I was starting activity from services till android P, but from android10 google has kept one restriction that activity cannot be started from background.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

```
// below code stopped working
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

what should i do for android10 ?

Comment: Well, on the very page you linked to it says _"In nearly all cases, apps that are in the background should display time-sensitive notifications to provide urgent information to the user instead of directly starting an activity."_

Comment: Yeah I would say from that document it is literally impossible on Android 10, would love to be corrected though. The intention is obviously to force the user to choose the launch of your activity via a notification, instead of developers automating it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a notification using `setFullScreenIntent`, it's the best you can do or you can ask for `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission but it doesn't work with android go devices.